# baseUrl in tsconfig.app.json is not overiding the baseUrl in tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, typescript2.0

In Angular 6, I'm using **ng generate application** as I will have more than one application which has to share some libraries. With this approach, I have folder structure like this:

> projects->app1->tsconfig.app.json
>
> projects->app2->tsconfig.app.json

And the **tsconfig.json** is in the same level as **projects** folder

**Note**: Folder structure like this will be created when we use **ng g application** in Angular 6.

I want to use relative paths in my components or services etc for imports like this:

> import { ExampleService } from 'src/services/example.service';

instead of having to use it something like this:

> import { ExampleService } from '../../../services/example.service';

How can I provide this features for the individual applications that are created like mentioned above?

My tsconfig.json is like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my tsconfig.app.json is like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I have tried giving like this in the tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

But that didn't work.

I want to use the relative paths by using **src** directly to eliminate the multiple level resolution `(../../../)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the `paths` compilerOption from `tsconfig.json`. With it you can do this for instance:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "@services/*": [
      "src/services/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can then import from any file inside your typescript project using this path:

```
import { ExampleService } from '@services/example.service';
```

<sub>No need to use `@`, you can name it whatever you like</sub>

Comment: But is it not possible to use the baseUrl inside tsconfig.app.json?

Comment: @sand maybe, but the issue you are having has the solution of setting a path, not by medling with the baseUrl :)

Comment: Yes. Since I am trying to restructure an already present application, I was hoping that just updating the baseUrl would do the trick :) Thanks though